# How to find a string between two begin and end strings in delphi?

Tags: delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi: Extract string from a text file using 2 delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950500/delphi-extract-string-from-a-text-file-using-2-delimiters)

How to find a string between two begin and end strings in Delphi

Comment: function ExtractText(const Str: string; const Delim1, Delim2: char): string;
  how can i use this function ? need sample

Comment: you change the type of the delimiters from "char" to string and you call it like this: `ExtractText('your text', 'begin', 'end'); But you might want to tell us exactly what you need this for. As I mentioned in my answer, if those two delimiters ("begin" and "end") are parts of actual code, this naive solution is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with a naive solution, look at this SO: [Extract string from a text file using 2 delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950500/delphi-extract-string-from-a-text-file-using-2-delimiters)

If you want to do it for code analyses you actually need an full language parser capable of understanding comments, conditional compilation + all other precompiler options.

Answer (score 2):

```
uses
  StrUtils;
...
const
  sBegin = 'begin';
  sEnd = 'end';
var
  i1, i2: Integer;
  sSubstr: String;
...
  i1 := Pos(sBegin, s);
  if i > 0 then begin
    i2 := PosEx(sEnd, s, i1 + Length(sBegin));
    if i2 > 0 then begin
      sSubstr := Copy(s, i1 + Length(sBegin), i2 - (i1 + Length(sBegin)));
      // process the delimited substring
    end;
  end;
```

Notes:

1. The code above is not verified.
2. Similar may be done by the regular expressions or with some limitations by the C/C++ sscanf.

Answer (score 1):

go to [Extract string from a text file using 2 delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950500/delphi-extract-string-from-a-text-file-using-2-delimiters)

Copy the function, and call it like this:

```
`ExtractText('Hi my name is$John and I''m happy/today','$','/')`;
```

It'll return 'John and I''m happy'.

Example:

```
ShowMessage(ExtractText('Hello,World!', ',' ,'!'));
```

It'll show 'World' in a popup.